# Matlab interp2 to scipy.interpd2 with matricies

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation

In Matlab I used

```
Vq = interp2(V,Xq,Yq)
```

Where *Xq* and *Yq* is **matricies**.

In Python I use

```
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(np.arange(w), np.arange(h), z, kind='cubic')
f(Xq, Yq)
```

And catching error

```
ValueError: x and y should both be 1-D arrays
```

How to use it if Xq and Yq is matricies. Sorry, I'm not very experienced in Matlab and scipy.

Comment: Is z a meshgrid like this website(https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/scipyinterpolateinterp2d/)?

Comment: @uozcan12 in my case z is matrix normalized image.

Comment: If your data grid locations (Xq,Yq) are regular (same spacing between every data point), then you can use interp2d, and you only have to provide a 1D array for the rows and columns of the grid. If your data grid locations are irregular, then you can use [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata), which takes a 2D array of data grid points.